Process DTEND in a partial ICS file
what I have is an already processed ICS file which contains these three lines for each event:
SUMMARY:"Description"
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230612
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230201

The dates can be in two forms:
DATE:20230201
DATE:20220908T153000

I need a bash script that sutracts one day from DTEND date if it's in the short form.
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230201 would be DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230131 after the script is through.
Dates in long format should be unchanged.
Tried with awk:
#!/bin/bash

# Input file
input_file="input_file.txt"
output_file="output_file.txt"

# Process the file with awk
awk '
/^DTEND;/ {
    # Extract the date part after "DTEND;"
    split($0, arr, ";")
    date = arr[length(arr)]
    
    # Check if the date format is YYYYMMDD (8 digits)
    if (match(date, /^[0-9]{8}$/)) {
        # Parse year, month, day
        year = substr(date, 1, 4)
        month = substr(date, 5, 2)
        day = substr(date, 7, 2)
        
        # Calculate the previous day using date command
        prev_date = strftime("%Y%m%d", mktime(year " " month " " day " 00 00 00") - 86400)
        
        # Replace the original date with the previous day date
        sub(date, prev_date, $0)
    }
}
{ print }
' "$input_file" > "$output_file"

echo "Processing complete. Output saved to $output_file"

But after running the script nothing happend to the dates in short format.
Guess i miss something.
Any help would be great ;-)
Ps.: No need to use awk, could also be sed or any other command that is available in bash.
Additional Info:
I also tried with another approach: Leave the last 4 digits of dates as 4 digit integer numbers and subtract 1 from that number. Therefor I need a case selection for month boundaries:
case 0201 then 0131
and so forth.
I can omit the january first problem (which would also alter the year since 20220101 - 1 -> 20211231) since there can not be a DTEND on the first of january.
But could not get this second approach to work neither.

You split your array on ; (semicolon). So you get 2 elements and the second is something like VALUE=DATE:20230612. Split on : (colon), instead. And you could use a more accurate regex to select the lines of interest: /^DTEND;VALUE=DATE:[0-9]{8}$/.

Made both changes. (Regex and delimiter) - but script still does not subtract 1 from date in DTEND. input and output files are identical afterwards.

See my answer. I tested it on your examples and it produces the expected output. Did you check your input for trailing spaces or DOS lines termination? ICS file frequently have DOS lines termination. If it is the case try /^DTEND;VALUE=DATE:[0-9]{8}\r$/.

My bad - it's the line termination that caused the problem. Thank you very much!

Regarding "The dates can be in two forms:" - if your real data can contain 2 different forms of date and you want to handle each differently in your script then show sample input/output that includes both forms. Don't show sample input with just one of them and then mention there could be another elsewhere. Give us an example we can simply copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

You split your array on ; (semicolon). So you get 2 elements and the second is something like VALUE=DATE:20230612. Split on : (colon), instead. And you could use a more accurate regex to select the lines of interest:
awk -F: -v OFS=: '/^DTEND;VALUE=DATE:[0-9]{8}\r?$/ {
  y=substr($2,1,4); m=substr($2,5,2); d=substr($2,7,2); r=substr($2,9)
  $2 = strftime("%Y%m%d", mktime(y " " m " " d " 0 0 0") - 86400) r}
  1' "$input_file" > "$output_file"

Note the \r? at the end of the regexp and the use of the r=substr($2,9) variable, such that this works with UNIX file format (lines terminated with \n) and DOS file format (lines terminated with \r\n).
Note: just like your own version this requires GNU awk for the strftime function.


No need to use awk, could also be sed or any other command that is
available in bash.

date command is able to determine date relative to provided date, for example
date --date="20230201 -1 day" "+%Y%m%d"

gives output
20230131

and could be used in script e.g. following way, let input_file.txt content be
SUMMARY:"Description"
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230612
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230201

then
IFS=$';:\r'
while read -r line; do
    read -ra arr <<< "$line"
    if [[ "${arr[0]}" == "DTEND" && ${#arr[2]} -eq 8 ]]; then
       prevday=$(date --date="${arr[2]} -1 day" "+%Y%m%d")
       echo "${arr[0]};${arr[1]}:$prevday"
    else
       echo "$line"
    fi
done < input_file.txt

gives output
SUMMARY:"Description"
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230612
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230131

Explanation: I inform bash that fields are separated by ; or : or \r (in case you have DOS line endings) then I use while loop to read input_file.txt line by line, I split each line into array named arr if field 0 is DTEND and field 2 has 8 characters, then I use date to detect previous day and compose newline from fields 0 and 1 and previous day, otherwise I output line as-is.

GNU date only for the -1 day part

Using GNU awk for it's time library, time functions and multi-char RS (to handle possible DOS line endings in the input mentioned in comments under the question):
$ awk '
    @load "time"
    BEGIN { RS="\r?\n"; FS=OFS=":"; fmt="%Y%m%d" }
    /^DTEND.*:[0-9]{8]$/ { $2 = strftime( fmt, strptime($2,fmt)-24*60*60 ) }
    { print }
' file
SUMMARY:"Description"
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230612
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230131

